# Python method to multithread two vastly different timed functions for MQTT

Tags: python, multithreading, mqtt

i have an application that samples two IOs at vastly different rates that need to operate within an MQTT reporting loop that sends messages every 5secs.  one function **must** sample every 10ms and increments a counter based on it's IO port value.  the other can run right before the MQTT message is sent, but takes about a full second to get the data it needs, parse it, and compile a message.  i'm not sure how to thread the two so that i'm not losing resolution on the critical method (10ms) while making the other runs it's loop (1sec) ultimately having them both ready to drop their MQTT messages into the queue at the 5sec mark.  frankly, i don't even know where to begin properly.  but here's what i've attempted as it relates to this question:

```py
import time
import concurrent.futures
import threading

elaspedTimeBeforeTX = 0

while True:

  while elapsedTimeBeforeTX < 4.900:
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        
      if elapsedTimeBeforeTX % .01 == 0:    #<-- do this every 10ms
        start1 = time.process_time()

        tickCount = executor.submit(sampleTickPort, tickPort)
        tickTotal += tickCount.result()

        end1 = time.process_time()
        elapsedTimeBeforeTX += (end1 - start1)
        print(f'→ → → tick sample time: {elapsedTimeBeforeTX}seconds ← ← ←')

      if 4 > elapsedTimeBeforeTX > 3.5: #<-- trigger this between 3.5 and 4 sec
        start2 = time.process_time()

        data = executor.submit(getJ1939data)
        j1939Data += data.result()

        end2 = time.process_time()
        loop2 = (end - start)
        print(f'→ → → j1939 sample time: {loop2}seconds ← ← ←')

  #  time to send MQTT message
  buildMessage(tickCount, j1939Data)
  payload.timestamp = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
  sendMQTTMessage(payload)
```

when i run this... well... `sampleTickPort` never stops, `getJ1939Data` never runs, and the fan on my system really starts to howl.  O_o  that's when i ***really*** know it's not working right.  somewhere my logic is failing.  can someone please point me in the right direction?  i also think where i increment my `elapsedTimeBeforeTX` is wrong, but i don't know *why* it's wrong or where to place it so it does what it's supposed to.

let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Given that `result()` waits for the `Future` to complete your code would have the same effect if you just called the function directly. Also consider what happens if neither condition is true (`elapsedTimeBeforeTX` would never change so you have an infinite loop). Consider starting two processes, one for `sampleTickPort` and the other for `getJ1939data` (both being loops with a `sleep` to wait the required time between polls).

Comment: i think i understand...  so what i could also have done was encapsulate everything under the 2nd `if...` statement in a function and thread *that*?  if i feel the need to tempt fate and my CPU, maybe i'll give it a shot.  :D  thanks for your advice.

Comment: Ideally you want to avoid tight loops (as this needlessly works your CPU). My default approach would be three threads (one for each polling frequency and one to send out the sample). Each polling thread can run a query and then calculate how long to [`sleep`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.sleep) before running the next poll (sleep gives the CPU a rest :-) ).

Comment: @Brits CPU hammering is a non-issue on this project.  since we're running this on a single processor ARM chip, i don't have the features i'd normally employ (multi-processing).  thanks for your advice.  FWIW, there's probably no sleep going on; this isn't the beefiest of CPUs...  :P  but i hear what you're saying and will definitely pass that to supply.  sorry for delay responding: life, right?

Comment: nope.  not gelling.  i understand what you mean about getting `result()` after submitting the executor, but i don't understand *where* to put it instead.  my JS knowledge is biting me in the butt a bit and i'm admittedly confused on how to manage this timing on a single processor...  :P  EDIT:  crap.  `concurrent.futures` IS a multiprocessing method.  i got a bad steer from the jump.  :(

Comment: nope.  i've hit the confusion boundary where the brain is trying to integrate new information and is a tornado of crap until it settles....

Comment: If you want to use `futures` then look at [`as_completed`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.as_completed) (see [this example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor-example)). Using this you can wait on the multiple futures and do something whenever one of them returns. However running three threads (see a [tutorial like this](https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/#working-with-many-threads)) is probably a simpler approach.

Comment: @Brits, you beautiful beast!  thank you.  :)  as you can tell, this is new territory for me and i appreciate your help and patience.

Comment: @Brit i'm thinking of going with the triple-thread approach, but the one thing that continues to elude me is how to keep the most important thread continuously running while getting data out of it.  or maybe i'm not grokking this fully yet.  the fast loop is critical.  it MUST be running every 10th of a second to poll for input changes.  i have tried just running a fast thread with no exit condition and updating a global variable inside the loop, but it isn't working.  :P

Comment: Effectively you will have two infinite polling loops running (they only terminate when the application terminates); these just poll then wait until the next poll is due. The other thread (probably simplest to run in the main thread) just waits until a sample is due; grabs data previously collected by the polling threads and sends it. There are complicating factors (e.g. what happens if a poll fails) but you would need to work around these whatever technique you choose. Note that Stack overflow is not a discussion forum so this may be better suited to another site.

Comment: @Brits fair point.  will shift to something more suitable.  thank you, though.